# Type error while writing max function

Tags: haskell

```
max' :: Int -> Int -> Int
max' a b = if a >= b then a else b
```

you see that the function is correct but if i write

```
let a = 3,
let b = 3
```

and also if i write

```
ghci> a == b => True
```

so it compares them then why it doesn't compare in my function

```
ghci> max' a b
```

error occurs why? or what is the right way to write it?

Sorry I am beginner if my question is silly forgive me for that and edit it if there is a need  for that Thanks

```
<interactive>:19:6:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Integer'
    In the first argument of max', namely `a'
    In the expression: max' a b
    In an equation for `it': it = max' a b

<interactive>:19:8:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Integer'
    In the second argument of max', namely `b'
    In the expression: max' a b
    In an equation for `it': it = max' a b
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: here it is <interactive>:19:6:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Integer'
    In the first argument of max', namely `a'
    In the expression: max' a b
    In an equation for `it': it = max' a b

<interactive>:19:8:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Integer'
    In the second argument of max', namely `b'
    In the expression: max' a b
    In an equation for `it': it = max' a b

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess you are doing this in the `ghci` interpreter. Then, have a look at (`:t` displays the type of an expression and a line of the form `a :: t` means `a` has type `t`):

```
Prelude> let a = 3
Prelude> :t a
a :: Integer
```

The `ghci` interpreter commits early and gives `a` the type `Integer` though it should give any numeric type (thus `a :: Num t => t`).

Now, your function receives `Int`s as arguments but since `a` and `b` are `Integer`s you get that error message.

You can either remove the restrictive type signature or you can define `a` and `b` to be `Int`s. I'd go with the first option, unless there is some requirement to go with `Int`-only type signature. To do so you need to add `::Int` at the end of the definition:

```
Prelude> let b = 42 :: Int
Prelude> :t b
b :: Int
```

If you want to remove the signature recode your function to have only one line:

```
max' a b = if a >= b then a else b
```

Now, if you're to inspect its type:

```
Prelude> :t max'
max' :: Ord a => a -> a -> a
```

Which means you've got a generic function which works for any type which can be ordered.

**An alternative** is to start `ghci` using an extension: `ghci -XNoMonomorphismRestriction`. In this case:

```
Prelude> let a = 3
Prelude> :t a
a :: Num a => a
```

which will work directly on your function.

The reason why `ghci` without this extension commits to `Integer` is the [Monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction)

Comment: You can also `:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction` inside GHCi.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `let a = 3`, the type of `a` will be `Integer`, not `Int`. You can check this by using `:t a` in `ghci`. You can use `let a = 3 :: Int` to ensure that you get the correct type:

```
ghci>let a = 3 :: Int
ghci>let b = 3 :: Int
ghci>max' a b
```

Comment: Why it becomes integer not int directly? and what are the differences between prelude or ghci?

Comment: If you don't explicitly annotate, the compiler has to make a choice. Choosing `Integer` here is a choice as good as any.

Comment: GHCi is GHC's interactive interpreter. Prelude is just a standard module that's always implicitly imported. It is what gives you functions such as `>=` that you have in your code above.

Comment: Yes you are right Integer is a choice as good as any so why specifically this ? does it have any privilege ?

Comment: @gspr It does not *have to* choose. Since all integer literals have an implicit `fromInteger` to them `ghci` could keep it as a general `Num a => a` value.

Comment: @kqr: Ah, yes, I agree. That was imprecise of me. @user2999428: Well, all the other integral types (such as `Int`) have limited range. I'm only speculating now, but I guess it's kinda nice that the chosen type can handle any integer you enter (given enough memory)?